# How to create a new variable in SAS by extracting part of the value of an existing numeric variable with a condition from a catagorical variable?

Tags: variables, sas, proc

I want to create a new variable called **Sales_of_win7** I have two variables one is  **Total sale** (Numeric variable)and another one is **ProductGRpID** which is a catagorical variable which contains(Two catagories: Win7 and Printers). So I want to create a variable **Sales_of_win7** by extracting value from **Total Sale** if it only win7 in **ProductGRpID**. How can I do that?. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post an example..rather than describing it in words?

Comment: you can use something like.. if ProductGRpID="Win7" then Sale_of_win7=Total_sale;

Answer (score 0):

```
data new;
 set old;
 if ProductGRpID = "Win7" then sales_of_win7 = total_sale;
run;
```

You could add an "else" statement if you want something specific to happen in other cases

Comment: But What if i want to compute it in PROC Report@Peter Flom, @NEOmen  my code goes like below 'proc report data = Practice.Cons_Sales nowd;
 columns Shop_ID Price Rev_Loss_by_windows7;
 define Shop_ID/group format=Shop_ID.;
 define price/analysis sum format=DOLLAR10.2;
 define Rev_Loss_by_windows7/computed format=DOLLAR10.2;
 *define Original_Revenue/computed format=DOLLAR10.2;
   Compute Rev_Loss_by_windows7;
        if ProductGRpID="Win7" then Rev_Loss_by_windows7 = Total_sale;
       endcomp;
run;
quit;'.

Comment: I don't know, I never use PROC REPORT